# is the time complexity of nested for-loops always of O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
   for (j = n; j >= i; j--)

}
```

I'm struggling with this algorithm. I can't even know what time complexity of this algorithm is? I've checked using online software it shows me only o(n).

Comment: Which online software tool did you use?

Comment: @templatetypedef I've searched something like big o calculate and result is on the top.

Comment: Can you post a link to that tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the algorithm should be something like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   for (j = n; j >= i; j--)
     DoSomeWork(i, j); // <- Payload which is O(1)
```

To find out the time complexity, let's count how many times `DoSomeWork` will be executed:

```
 i :    j : executed, times 
----------------------------
 1 : 1..n : n
 2 : 2..n : n - 1
 3 : 3..n : n - 2
.. :  ...   ...  
 n : n..n : 1
```

So far so good, `DoSomeWork` will be executed

```
  n + n - 1 + n - 2 + ... + 2 + 1 = (n + 1) * n / 2
```

times; time complexity for *your case* is

```
O((n + 1) * n / 2) = O((n + 1) * n) = O(n * n) + O(n) = O(n * n)
```

Nested loops are not necessary have quadratic time complexity, e.g.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   for (j = n; j >= i; j /= 2) // note j /= 2, instead of j--
     DoSomeWork(i, j);
```

has `O(n * log(n))` time complexity

Comment: All of this, provided DoSomeWork is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Think about this a little. How many times do we enter into the outer loop? It's n times, as you surely already know, since we have step1, ..., stepn, in total n steps.

So, we have

**n * average(inner)**

In the first step, the inner loop has n steps. Then it has n - 1 steps and so on, on the final step we have 1 step in the inner loop.

so, the inner loop has:

n, n-1, ..., 1 steps in the respective iterations.

Since addition is both commutative and associative, we have:

(n + 1) + (n - 1 + 2) + ...

that is (n+1)/2 on average.

Since we worry about the scenario when n -> infinity, adding 1 to it or dividing it by 2 is less of a concern, so we roughly have n * n steps, hence it has a complexity of O(n * n), don't listen to the tool that says otherwise, unless you have some extra information about your algorithm to share with us.

Comment: I should mention that if the operation that's being executed inside the loops is complex, then of course it needs to be taken into account.